# How to select the records that are NOT MAX() in query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I need to be able to view a column in a table that has duplicates in it. Currently I can use MIN() and MAX() to and see results. However it's not being reliable (records could appear more than twice). How can I see the max records in one column while viewing all the records that are NOT MAX in another?

An example of results in looking for.

My current column structure:

```
200   111
200   111
300   111
300   111
400   111
400   111
```

How I want it to look is basically:

```
Records.   Max value for records    
200           400
200           400
300           400
```

Currently I can use this query

```
Select MIN(Id), MAX(ID)
From table
Group by ANOTHERID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

That will give me:

```
200    400
```

But does not include the 300 I would need for my results.

That way I can determine what the MAX value is based on grouped ID's

Comment: 300 has no duplicates in your sample data. It does not fit `count(*)>1` condition.

Comment: Edited. It was supposed to sorry.

Comment: Post corresponding `ANOTHERID` values since your are grouping by this column.

Comment: Edited. They would be the same ID that's why I didn't include them.

Comment: MySql or MSSQL? Feels like there was only MSSQL tag a minute ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    ID AS NON_MAX_VALUES, (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM TABLE ) AS MAX_VALUE
FROM 
    TABLE
GROUP BY 
    ID 
HAVING 
    COUNT(*)>1
    AND
    ID NOT IN (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM TABLE)
```

Comment: Tried that as well and I get zero results. Looking at it from a basic point of view I'm not sure why this wouldn't work. My because the initial ID select is also selecting the MAX value?

Comment: @Lynx , i have tested this on my local system. It is working fine as you wished